# How do I test a Test::Builder test?

Tags: perl, testing

I'm writing a module with [`Test::Builder`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/Builder.html). I want to write a test to that tests my test when it's *failing*. Unfortunately a failing test in a test makes that test fail, and thus my whole test suite fails. How can I test failing tests? so that they don't cause my test suite to fail. *code examples appreciated*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Test::Builder::Tester`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/Builder/Tester.html) is included in the Test::Builder/Test::Simple distribution and contains functions for testing any kind of test module that uses Test::Builder (Test::Simple, Test::More, and the great majority of well-behaved recent test modules).

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at the test suites of [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore) or [`Test::Most`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMost).

And I'd make sure they don't cover my needs - which I assume you have done. ;-)

Comment: Please explain how Test::More or Test::Most can be used to test a failing test, in a way that doesn't make the test suite fail.

Comment: @xenoterracide - I think the point was to look at test suite of those modules. In addition I would look into `t/Builder` directory of `Test::Simple` distribution.

Comment: @bvr @michael oh I misread. I should probably go to bed now... too tired for coding more today, esp reading someone elses code.